# Array connected button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How do I make a button that is attached to an array? I want to be able to take the following code and connect it, as my array, to a button:

```js
const quotesArray = [
  "Here is quote 1",
  "Here is quote 2",
  "Here is quote 3",
 ];

 // Get DOM elements that we will listen to and change.
 const currentQuote = document.getElementById("current-quote");
 const getNextQuote = document.getElementById('get-next-quote');

 // Set initial quote to display
 currentQuote.innerHTML = quotesArray[0];


 // Set a variable to keep track the next quote to display.
 let i = 1;

 // Listen for a click and set HTML to the next quote in the array.
 getNextQuote.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const nextQuote = quotesArray[i];
 currentQuote.innerHTML = nextQuote;

 // Update i. Set i to 0 if we've reached the end of the array.
 if (i === quotesArray.length - 1) {
   i = 0;
 } else {
  i += 1;
 }
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="get-next-quote">Get Next Quote</div>
</div>

<div id="current-quote"></div>
```

I am not sure what part I need to attach to the array and I want to do more with it, but I just want to figure out how you take an array and be able to access it directly from a button. Would anyone be able to explain this to me?

Comment: Please, explain why you want to "access" an array by a button and what exactly does it mean? it doesn't seems to make sense

Comment: Have you tried changing your "get-next-quote" div element to a button element?

Comment: what do you mean by attach a button to an array ? by the way, in your `HTML` code I don't see any `button` tag I only see `div` tags with `ID`s that being used in your `JavaScript` code.